# VoidMessage response failing on Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've create a small Google Cloud Endpoints Frameworks application running on App Engine - Standard Environment. Overall, things have been working very nicely.

I need to create a method that simply returns as HTTP 204 once it is called via HTTP GET. As I understand it, this can be accomplished by simply returning message_types.VoidMessage().

However, when I use this approach, the endpoint returns an HTTP 500 error. From the error console, the error reported is:

> ValueError: response_size should be a positive int/long

My method is essentially empty right now (just logging) - the error does not originate until the response is attempted.

Traceback:

> (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:279)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
>       result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/..../lib/google/api/control/wsgi.py", line 194, in **call**
>       return self._application(environ, start_response)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/..../lib/google/api/control/wsgi.py", line 574, in **call**
>       return self._application(environ, start_response)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/..../lib/google/api/control/wsgi.py", line 323, in **call**
>       rules)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/..../lib/google/api/control/wsgi.py", line 356, in _create_report_request
>       url=app_info.url
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/..../lib/google/api/control/report_request.py", line 241, in **new**
>       _validate_int_arg('response_size', response_size)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/..../lib/google/api/control/report_request.py", line 45, in _validate_int_arg
>       raise ValueError('%s should be a positive int/long' % (name,))
>   ValueError: response_size should be a positive int/long

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

I'm on App Engine Standard edition.

google-endpoints is v2.0.0b5

google-endpoints-api-management is v1.0.0b6

Comment: I am not developing in python but in java and I can confirm that if you do the equivalent in java (i.e. API method response type is void) it sends back an HTTP 204 code, according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions. Python equivalent is (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions) so it should work for you

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I'm working on a fix right now that should resolve this issue. It will go out in the next version of google-endpoints-api-management (which can be upgraded by running pip install -t lib --upgrade google-endpoints from your application's root directory).

Comment: @BradFriedman Awesome! I'll watch for the patch.